measurability to solutions of SDEs
Consider a stochastic differential equation $$dZ(t)=\theta(t)dB(t)$$where $B(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion. Denote by $\{\mathcal{F}_t^Z\}$ and $\{\mathcal{F}_t^B\}$ the natural filtration of $Z(t)$ and $B(t)$ respectively. I have two questions as follows:

Under what assumption is it guaranteed that $\theta(t)$ is adapted to $\{\mathcal{F}_t^Z\}$?

If $\theta(t)$ is indeed adapted to $\{\mathcal{F}_t^Z\}$, is it true that $\mathcal{F}_t^Z\subset\mathcal{F}_t^B$?


My clue to question 1: If $\theta(t)$ is non-negative and left-continuous, write $Z(t)=\int_0^t\theta(s)dB(s)$ to obtain $$\langle Z,Z\rangle_t=\int_0^t\theta^2(s)ds.$$This implies that $$\theta^2(t)=\underset{s\uparrow t}{\lim}\frac{1}{t-s}(\langle Z,Z\rangle_t-\langle Z,Z\rangle_s)$$ and therefore $\theta(t)$ is adapted to $\{\mathcal{F}_t^Z\}$.
Please help by giving weaker assmuptions on $\theta(t)$ to question 1 and proving question 2 either true or false.

These are weird questions. $B$ is a B.M. with respect to its own filtration $\cal F^B$ or perhaps a larger filtration $\cal F,.$ In order that the stochastic integral of $\theta$ is defined one assumes integrability and measurability conditions on $\theta,.$ Please look up the notion of progressive measurability. This implies the adaptedness of $Z,.$

(Assuming that $\{\theta(t)\}$ is adapted to $\{\mathcal F^B_t\}$.)
It is true, as you argue, that $\theta(t)^2$ is adapted to $\{\mathcal F^Z_t\}$, but the sign of $\theta(t)$ need not be, unless $\theta(t)\ge 0$.
Consider, for example, $Z(t) = |B(t)|-L(t)$, where $L$ is the local time in state $0$ of the Brownian motion $B$. Your SDE holds with  $\theta(t) ={\rm sign}(B(t))$, but $\mathcal F^Z_t$ is a proper subset of $\mathcal F^B_t$.
